# iOS Swift 2 - AVAudioPlayer OR AudioToolbox short beep from a NSTimer triggered time

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, audiotoolbox

I have a countdown timer that I want to play a beep at start and finish. The timer is supposed to be accurate to .01 of a second. With that, I also have a short .5 sec beep.mp3.

My question is, what is better in this situation where the beep HAS to be exactly at the right time. So if the user selects the stop of the timer at .08 of a second, then it will beep exactly at .08.

Should I use AVAudioPlayer or AudioToolbox with it's audioServicesPlaySystemSound?

Thanks!

Comment: Before asking a question,  try to implement a few versions yourself and then come the Stackoverflow with your failed attempts and explain what isn't going as planned. NSTimer is most likely not going to be accurate enough for your purposes. Look into using a CADisplayLink, it is supposed to be the most accurate/precise timer available in iOS, down to 1/60 of a second, which is equal to the refresh rate of the UI. I've also used `dispatch_after` for +/-10milisec accuracy and found it to be acceptable. Once you have an accurate timer, `AVAudioPlayer` should be accurate enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. I felt like NSTimer was effectively showing correct time, but the play of the sound was off. I will come back with some code after a few more tests.